# How to debug ms access query?

Tags: ms-access

If I run a query in ms access and receive errors in running the query. I clicked the help popup. If the help popup does not help me debug the query, what other resources can I use?

Comment: Did you use query designer to construct the SQL? What kind of error?

Comment: It really depends on the error type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no debugger for queries. Simplify your query in small steps until the error has gone. Then you know that the last simplification contained the bug.